# Nginx proxy catch own errors

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I've spent several hours on trying to figure this out and looking for answers, but I can't seem to find a way to get things working.

Basically I want to use Nginx as a reverse proxy for my docker setup. That's pretty simple. Here's my configuration, below that I'll explain my problem.

```
server {
    server_name ~^(.*)$;
    resolver 127.0.0.11;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    proxy_pass_header Server;

    location / {
        proxy_pass $scheme://$1;

        error_page 500 502 = @catch;
    }

    location @catch {
        proxy_pass $scheme://apache;
    }
}
```

So here's my problem. I want the location @catch to be a fallback, if the first location doesn't exist. Here's an example:
Let's say I want to open the site `foo.com`. If `foo.com` is reachable, everything that's being return should be returned by Nginx. But if `foo.com` is not reachable I want to catch the error page and call the location @catch instead.

I know I could add `proxy_intercept_errors on`, but if `foo.com` returns a 500 page, that page will be "catched" too and I don't want that to happen.

I only want to catch error pages produced by Nginx, when an url is not reachable.

Can anybode help me with that?

Thank you.

Edit: I'll try to explain a bit better what I'm trying to do and what's my problem.

I have a container running Nginx which should do nothing, but act as a reverse proxy and pass requests to the corresponding container.
I have a container called `apache` which should act as a fallback container, if there is no docker container in available with the requested domain as the container name.

Example:
There are 3 containers running and this are their names:

- `nginx`
- `apache`
- `foo.com`

Now the container `nginx` gets a request for `foo.com`, the request should be passed to that container. If the apache returns an error with 500, that error message should be sent to the client.

But if the `nginx` gets a request for `bar.baz`, the nginx won't find a container with that name and produce an own 500 or 502 error. Only in this case I want to pass the request to the `apache` container. But if the `apache` container now returns an error with code 500, this error should be passed to the client.

To cut a long story short: I need a way to catch errors which are produced in or by Nginx, but not if they come from a backend.

Comment: Consider [try_files](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files)

Comment: @Tim I tried that, but as of my understanding try_files isn't suitable, since I'm not checking for a file, but for a server.

Comment: I don't see how these cases are related. I edited my question and tried to explain my problem a bit better.

Comment: I think you should read the linked question again, as well as what 400/404/500/502 [error codes mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). I think you're trying to catch the wrong codes - either that or I don't fully understand your question.

Comment: I know what the error codes mean. I think I have a problem to clearly explain, what I want to achieve.
I need a way to test if a proxy_pass backend exists and if not pass the request to another backend. I tried it using the error codes, but that might be the wrong way.
I need something like `try_files`, but for proxy backends instead of files.

Answer (score 0):

I just found why it wasn't working as expected. I'm using Nginx in a docker container, which automatically uses the hosts file from host system.

My server_name directive is taking the whole hostname (like `foo.com`). In my hosts file I redirect `foo.com` to `127.0.0.1`. Now if my configuration uses the full hostname (`foo.com` in this case), it will "find" a corresponding ip. So I changed my config a little bit to look like this:

```
server {
    server_name ~^(?<domain>.*)(\..*)$;
    resolver 127.0.0.11;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    proxy_pass_header Server;

    location / {
        proxy_pass $scheme://$domain;

        error_page 500 502 = @catch;
    }

    location @catch {
        proxy_pass $scheme://apache;
    }
}
```

Now Nginx will look for a container named `foo` instead of `foo.com`. If there is no container named `foo` this will fail as expected and be processed by the `@catch` location.